# es2015 modules - how to name exports dynamically

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6

I would like to create a module, `h`, which exports one function for every HTML element. Here's how it might be used:

```
import {div, p} from 'h'

const myDiv = div(p('some text'))
```

Here's how that module is defined:

```
const h = {}
for (let tagName of ['div', 'p', /* ... */]) {
  h[tagName] = (...children) => {
    // ...
  }
}

export const div = h.div
export const p = h.p
/* ... */
```

I don't like that every export has to be listed explictly. How do I make these dynamic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> how to name exports dynamically

You can't. `import` and `export` statements are specifically designed this way because they have to be statically analyzable, i.e. the import and export names have to be known **before** the code is executed.

If you need something dynamic then do what you are already doing: Export a "map" (or object). People can still use destructuring to just get what they want:

```
const {div} = h;
```

Comment: @MarkFox: a dynamic `import()` is not an `import` *statement*

Comment: @Bergi true a dynamic `import()` expression is different from a static `import` statement… but is this arcane semantic distinction readily available to someone who doesn't have the spec memorized? I doubt it. To my mind skipping mention of "import" does no disservice to the crispness of the answer.