# How to re-export a modified list of imported functions in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I want to create an ES6 module which imports all functions from another module, wraps these functions and exports them again. Sounds easy, but I can't get it working.

Let's start with the module with the functions I want to wrap:

```js
/* funcs.mjs */
export function foo() { return "foo"; };
export function bar() { return "bar"; };
// A lot of more functions following...
```

And this is a test script which imports and executes two of the many many hypothetical functions in the other module:

```js
/* test.mjs */
import { foo, bar } from "./funcs.mjs";

console.log(foo());
console.log(bar());
```

I now want to write a wrapper module which imports all functions from `funcs.mjs`, wrap them into new functions and export these new functions under the original function names. So in the end I want to be able to change the imported module name in `test.mjs` from `funcs.mjs` to `wrapped-funcs.mjs` and then without changing anything else this script must still work and now call the wrapped functions.

The problem I struggle with is that I can't figure out how to export the wrapped functions so they can be imported the same way as importing the original functions:

```js
/* wrapped-funcs.mjs */
import * as funcs from "./funcs.mjs";

const wrapped = Object.entries(funcs).reduce((wrapped, [ name, func ]) => {
    wrapped[name] = () => "wrapped " + func();
    return wrapped;
}, {});

// export wrapped;                     // Invalid
// export { ...wrapped };              // Invalid
// export { wrapped }                  // Not what I want (Exports object with name "wrapped")
// export default wrapped;             // Not what I want (Exports object with name "default")
export const { foo, bar } = wrapped;   // Exports correctly but I have to specify all functions manually
```

With `export { wrapped }` and `export default wrapped` I export all functions but the  module interface is different to what I want so that doesn't work. With `export const { foo, bar } = wrapped` the exports are structured correctly but this solution has the problem that I have to know all function names within the wrapper module. So that doesn't work, too.

Is there some other clever way to do this with ES6 modules? I know it can be done with CommonJS but that's out-of-scope here.

Comment: Probably dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684154/es2015-modules-how-to-name-exports-dynamically . I'd export a single object instead of using named exports in `wrapped-funcs.mjs`

Comment: You can't. exports are required to be statically analyzable. Your code is dynamic, and so the exports can't be created via static syntax. There is no ESM dynamic export syntax as there is in CommonJS and such. You could export an object with the functions on it as properties, but I'm sure you already know that's not the same and can't be imported using named imports.